# Azure B2C token scope permission issue

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, aad-b2c

When I try to get a token with a scope inside it then I get a `This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation` error.

```
Failing call:
https://xx.b2clogin.com/xx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=somepolicy&client_id=xx-xx&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7223/&scope=https://xx.onmicrosoft.com/xx-xx/Some.Scope&response_type=token
```

I can call it with the `openid` scope but then there are no scopes in the token. As I understand you need to set the `response_type=token` and `scope` to the actual scope of your api.

```
Working call but no scopes
https://xx.b2clogin.com/xx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=somepolicy&client_id=xx-xx&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7223/&scope=openid&response_type=id_token
```

I've alreay added the API to the permissions of the client and granted admin consent so that can't be the issue.
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Or is it maybe not possible to use scopes with a B2C token?

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried in my environment, and I got the token successfully.**

To resolve the error, please check the below **steps**:

In my case, I added a scope named **“newscope”** and then granted **API permissions** like below:

***Go to Azure portal -> Azure AD B2C -> App registrations ->Your application -> Expose an API -> Add Scope***

[image]
[image]
***To get token, try with below URL:***

```
https://xxxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=somepolicy&client_id=your_app_id&nonce=defaultnonce&redirect_uri=https://jwt.io&scope=openid profile offline_access&response_type=token&prompt=login
```

With the above authorization URL, I got the token like below that displayed the scopes successfully after decoding.

[image]

- Please make sure to add additional scope like **profile**, **offline_access** along with **open_id**.
- Here I have given **`response_type=token`** instead of **id_token**
- In Authentication blade, make sure to check mark both access token and id token.

[image]

- If still something goes wrong, try with **lower case scopes**.

Comment: if using a SPA for your app you shouldn't be using implicit flow as it isn;t secure ... you should be using auth flow with pkce